# Не строится проект при добавлении Yandex карт (mapkit)

Tags: android, android-studio, yandexmapkit

Хочу добавить Yandex карты и добавляю зависимость в Gradle:

```
  dependencies {
        implementation 'com.yandex.android:mapkit:3.4.0'  

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    }


allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://maven.google.com/"
        }
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

При построении решения Gradle ругается. В чём может быть проблема

> ERROR: Failed to resolve:
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2 Show in Project
>   Structure dialog Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0 Show
>   in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Failed to resolve: core Affected Modules: app

Comment: добавьте еще и `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0`

Comment: Добавил, ошибка сохранилась ERROR: Failed to resolve: core
Affected Modules: app

Comment: Вы именно добавили? У вас же написано что не разрешены зависимости, внимательно поссмотрите, каких-то пакетов у вас написано дважды, например: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2, вам нужно было поменять 11,6,2 на 17,0,0. Проверьте остальные на дубликаты

Comment: Добавил зависимости и всёравно осталась ошибка ERROR: Failed to resolve: core
Affected Modules: app

Comment: @Geferson, было бы чудесно если бы вы скинули сюда весь gradle файл

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57962613/error-failed-to-resolve-core-affected-modules-app, обновите все либы, которые подчеркиваются желтым до свежих версий (последние версии google либ тут: https://maven.google.com/web/index.html ) и ретрофит, с прилегающими ему, обновите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в санкциях, вопрос удалось решить тем. что я подключил прокси. И пакеты подгрузились.